# Trying to mint a token using metaboss and getting this error

Tags: metaboss

Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://devnet.genesysgo.net/): error trying to connect: error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1883: (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)

Caused by:
RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending request for url (https://devnet.genesysgo.net/): error trying to connect: error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:../ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:1883: (self-signed certificate in certificate chain)

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLI tools like Metaboss that need you to interact with Solana usually require you to customize the RPC endpoint you want to use. In your case, it looks like you are using an invalid RPC address to try and connect to devnet. There's 2 parts to this problem.

First, the network you choose to access matters. Testnet is generally for validators to test new versions of the network, Devnet is where developers test programs and code without spending real money on deploys and transactions, and Mainnet is where real activity takes place onchain. If you want to use devnet for creating a test token, great, you will just need a valid devnet RPC. One option would be the default Solana Devnet RPC, although this is heavily rate-limited. You can look at the Metaboss docs to see how to pass this in to different commands.

Solana Devnet RPC - https://api.devnet.solana.com

Second, using a valid RPC is important. You're trying to use a GenesysGo RPC endpoint, but GenesysGo stopped operating their RPC services a while ago. You will need to use the default RPCs or find an active RPC provider in order to get a valid RPC endpoint to use with Metaboss. There are lots of resources about Solana RPC providers for mainnet and devnet available via google or the official docs.

Once you have a valid RPC endpoint configured it should resolve the Metaboss error that you've shared here. For better help next time, please also share the Metaboss command you were using that generated this error.

Comment: you are absolutely right, I forgot to connect to the Mainnet cluster... Doing the 

solana config set --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com fixed it

I appreciate your guidance!